# How to change interface direction in Windows?

Tags: windows, language, user-interface, right-to-left

I am currently using Windows 10 in English, which is a left-to-right language. But I wish I can still have English as my system and interface language, but the whole interface is reversed from left-to-right to right-to-left, as in Hebrew or Arabic, I guess. I know it is possible, as I have seen some [screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Dm6.png) with right-to-left English interface in Windows 10, but I have no idea, how I can do it. I have already looked for the solution, and I only found one answer, which described editing current locale with Locale Builder. I have tried it, but it didn't work at all.